# PostGreSQL Create Function from VBA

Tags: function, postgresql, vba

I have set up an ADO connection to a PostgreSQL database.  I was wondering if it were possible from VBA to create functions - e.g I have a DatabaseSetUp function, creating tables and whatnot.  I was hoping that I could then add in some functions from VBA.

Possible?  If so, could I trouble someone for an example

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you mean here. Are you trying to create stored procedures/in-database functions written in VBA? Use VBA to create PL/PgSQL stored procs/functions? What?

Comment: Sorry was a late night question.  I want to create pgSQL funtions from vba and store them in a newly deployed database.  A setup/install sub in vba that creates the db, creates tables, then creates funtions that I want to have in the db

Comment: statement for function creating is usual SQL statement like other SQL statements. Just send to database SQL command like "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ...". There are no some special access necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as any other SQL like ordinary `SELECT`s. Just send the SQL.

You might want to query `pg_proc`, `pg_class`, etc (or the `information_schema`) to determine what already exists, though most statements have `IF EXISTS` or `CREATE OR REPLACE` variants.